# Is there a correct way to write the solution to a maximization problem as a function of parameters (i.e. constants or exogenous variables)

Tags: functions, optimization, notation

Suppose that we have four **constants**, $1>s>0, A>1, B>1,1>t>0$. (by constants I mean exogenous variables)

Also suppose that we have a function of three variables (defined on the positive reals): $F(w,y,z)$

Then suppose that we wish to solve the following maximization problem:

$$\max_x F \left(B+A-x,x,\frac{x-A-t}{1-s}\right),$$

where $F$ is strictly quasi concave. (if necessary also assume that the optimum occurs in the interior, but if this is needed please say so)

The first order condition for this maximization problem is:

$$\tag{2}
-F_w+ F_y+F_z \frac{1}{1-s}=0
$$

Are we able to write the $x$ that solves (2) as
$$
x^* = f(B+A, \frac{A+t}{1-s},s)
$$

where $f$ is some function, and where I use $x^*$ to denote the $x$ that solves (2)

If so, why?

> Specifically, how do we know the function $f$ takes as arguments $B+A$, $\frac{A+t}{1-s}$, $s$?
>
> - Would it be incorrect to instead write $x^*=f(B+A,\frac{A+t}{1-s})$?
>
>   - I feel like it would be, because if we imagine changing $s$ but keeping ${A+t}{1-s}$ the same the solution would change, as the result of $F_z\frac{1}{1-s}$ changing
> - What about writing it as $x^*=f(A,B,s,t)$?
>
>   - this one is much less clear to me whether we can write it as this, because yes it depends on these 4 constants, but there are interdepencies between them.

In general (i.e. not directly related to this question), I get confused when writing a function of variables as a function of different variables,

As an example, I believe we could write $(c+d)*w + u^h = g(c,d,h) = h(w,u)$. I.e., we could write this same function as taking different arguments.

In this example, I get that what we take as the variables is likely a judgement call on whatever we believe are independent variables and what are constants, but the earlier case of $f(B+A,\frac{A+t}{1-s},s)$ vs $f(A,B,s,t)$ is much less clear to me

---

Edit to clarify notation: My notation of $F_w$ means the derivative of the function $F$ with respect to $w$.

$w$ appears as the first argument, so of course you could instead use the notation $F_1$ instead of $F_w$ If you prefer

Also note that, when I wrote the first order condition, obviously the derivatives should be evaluated at the relevant point.

Comment: I am very confused---you seem to be asking two different questions.  In the first, you have a function $F$, which has three parameters, where the parameters depend on three different variables.  You then want notation to describe fixing two of those parameters and maximizing with respect to the third.

Comment: Your second question seems to be about writing a variable as a function of two other variables; that is, how to write $x$ as a function $G$ of $y$ and $z$.  I am not sure that I see how these two questions are related.  Can you please expand on this a little?

Comment: @Xander The OP is interested in writing down the maximiser of a function of $x$, $y$ and $z$ wrt $x$, which will, in general, be a function of $y$ and $z$. However in their problem it turns out to be a function of $y+z$ and $z$, so I think they're asking about why you would want to express the solution that way. The first part explains the context for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways of writing it are equivalent. To see this, Let $\hat z = z + y$. Then, your optimisation problem is now given by $$ \max_x F\left(\hat z - x,x,x-y\right). $$

If the maximiser is unique, then the $x$ that solves the maximisation problem is a function of $\hat z$ and $y$. That is, it is a function of $z+y$ and $y$.

Given a function $G$, we can always define another function $H$ such that $H(z,y)=G(z+y,y)$, so writing $x$ as $G(z,y)$ appears to be more general. But given the discussion above, you lose nothing about considering a function of $z+y$ and $y$ instead, but you might gain something if it simplifies some of your other notation.

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick follow up question: why the qualification "If the maximizer is unique"? (alternatively, if you know of a resource that discusses this, I'm happy to look into it myself)

Comment: There needs to be one maximiser for you to be able to write it down as a function of the parameters. If there is more than one, then you need to specify which one you're talking about. Otherwise, your function is not well-defined. (Recall that a function needs to specify a unique element in the range for each member of the domain.)